# Angular 4 populate form and set to untouched

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Created an update form, that basically is populated with information.

What I want is for the button to be disabled, until the info within the form is changed

The form group is using valuechanges to listen when info has been edited

But the form is always touched, even if I change using

```
this.formGroup.markAsUntouched()
```

The form itself does register the fact that I've set it to untouched

```
setFormValues(){
      this.firstNameControl.setValue(user.firstName);
      this.lastNameControl.setValue(user.lastName);
      this.emailControl.setValue(user.email);
      this.userNameControl.setValue(user.userName);
      this.emailControl.setValue(user.email);
  //Tried setting here this.formGroup.markAsUntouched()
}

onFormChanges() {
    return this.formGroup.valueChanges
    .subscribe(val => {
        //Can set here but will always be untouched, as well if I use 
       this.formGroup.markAsUntouched()
        console.log(this.count, this.formGroup.valid, this.formGroup.touched, this.formGroup.dirty)

    });
  }
```

I understand the above will always be untouched, but if I omit that, it executes twice on init and sets the form to touched, because, i suppose, the information from the db is loaded, have tried using a counter var; if counter == 2 (second iteration) of valuechanges then this.formGroup.markAsUntouched()

Which works, another thing is the html doesn't seem to register that the formgroup is disabled

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-complimentary" type="submit" [disabled]="!formGroup.touched">
```

Comment: I use a combination of touched and dirty to manage the status of my button

Answer (score 6):

To handle this kind of behavior in my forms, I use a combination of `pristine` and `valid` (use `valid` only if you have some validation on your fields). I don't use `touched` because you can touch an input without changing its value.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.pristine || !formGroup.valid">
```

After sending the data to the server, if you want to re-disable the button, you can use the [`reset()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset) function of your `formGroup`

> Resets the form control. This means by default:
>
> - it is marked as pristine
> - it is marked as untouched
> - value is set to null
>
> You can also reset to a specific form state by passing through a standalone value or a form state object that contains both a value and a disabled state (these are the only two properties that cannot be calculated).

Like it said, you can provide the new state of your form in the first parameter of `reset()`

Comment: The form is populated with info from a database, so is set to touched and pristine

Comment: You can pass the info from the database into the reset function, so your form can be populated and pristine. I don't think you should care about the touched state

Comment: I had to use a polyfill for the time input.  It touched the form in material mat-form-field.  There are cases it makes sense.  I am working on this now.

Answer (score 5):

To set form again untouched we can simply use

```
this.form.markAsUntouched();
```

and if you want to set it to pristine

```
this.form.markAsPristine();
```

Note: We can also set a particular control of form to untouched or pristine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> markAllAsTouched()

```
this.formName.markAllAsTouched();
```

Comment: I think the OP's objective is to set them untouched, not touched.